# How to log a the creation date of a google drive folder in a spreadsheets script?

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my first google apps script and the original plan was to do something way more comlplicated, but I got stuck in the very beginning.

Now, I just want to log the creation date of my folder, and I can't.

When I press ctr+enter there's nothing to see in the logs window.

Why is this happening? I am not trying to build a rocket here...

Here's my code :

```
fetchFiles();
  function fetchFiles() {

  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Aff Comm");

    Logger.log(folder.next().getDateCreated());

}
```

Comment: In the toolbar of the code editor, there is a drop down list of function names.  "Select Function"  Did you select the function name, and click the "Run" button?  You don't need the `fetchFiles();` call in the global scope.  If the code runs at all, then something will show up in the Execution Transcript.  There are no "quick keys" to open the Execution Transcript.  Choose the "View" menu and Execution Transcript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, just tested in my Script, works. But:

- you need to save your script (extremely important). If there is the red asterisk a in the image below you have not saved your code
- you need to select `fetchFiles` in the dropdown menu  (the one in the red rectangle in the image below, if you did not save, the function may be unavailable in the dropdown menu)
- at the first run you agree with the permission request from google

[image]

You may improve your code in this way:

```
function fetchFiles() {
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Aff Comm");
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
   var folder = folders.next();
   Logger.log(folder.getDateCreated());
 }
}
```